# Visualizing Iron Phases in a 3D Plot: Changing Solid Color at Intersection Points

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, diagram

I have a MATLAB script that generates a 3D plot representing iron phases under different operating conditions. The plot consists of three 3D lines that intersect with a solid, where the solid represents the iron phases. I would like to modify the script so that the color of the solid changes at the points where the 3D lines intersect it. This color change will help visually recognize the iron phases (iron, wustite, or magnetite) at specific operating conditions.

Could you provide guidance on how to implement this color change in the MATLAB script? Specifically, how can I modify the existing code to achieve this effect? Any suggestions or code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the current state of the plot:

[image: iron phases]

*Edit: Please find below a copy of the desired graph. I crudely drew this

[image]*

Here is the existing MATLAB code for reference:

```
R = 8.314; % J/mol/K
p = 1; % atm

% Script 1
T1 = 700:10:1200;
ov_x_co1 = [];
ov_x_h21 = [];

for i = 1:numel(T1)
    % Calculation for Script 1
    k6 = exp((-10034 -38.635*T1(i)*log(T1(i))+271.78*T1(i))./(-R.*T1(i)));
    k7 = exp((26546-38.635*T1(i)*log(T1(i))+238.315*T1(i))./(-R.*T1(i)));
    k2 = exp((172140 - 177.7.*T1(i))./(-R.*T1(i)));

    x_co = k6 * k2 / p;
    x_h2 = (p-k6*k2*(k6+1))/(p*(k7+1));

    ov_x_co1 = [ov_x_co1; x_co];
    ov_x_h21 = [ov_x_h21; x_h2];
end

% Script 2
T2 = 700:10:1200;
ov_x_co2 = [];
ov_x_h22 = [];

for i = 1:numel(T2)
    % Calculation for Script 2
    k6 = exp((-21785+25*T2(i))./(-R.*T2(i)));
    k7 = exp((14799-8.465*T2(i))./(-R.*T2(i)));
    k2 = exp((172140 - 177.7.*T2(i))./(-R.*T2(i)));

    x_co = k6 * k2 / p;
    x_h2 = (p-k6*k2*(k6+1))/(p*(k7+1));

    ov_x_co2 = [ov_x_co2; x_co];
    ov_x_h22 = [ov_x_h22; x_h2];
end

% Script 3
T3 = 700:10:1200;
ov_x_co3 = [];
ov_x_h23 = [];

for i = 1:numel(T3)
    % Calculation for Script 3
    k6 = exp((-18844 -9.66*T3(i)*log(T3(i))+86.695*T3(i))./(-R.*T3(i)));
    k7 = exp((17736-9.66*T3(i)*log(T3(i))+52.23*T3(i))./(-R.*T3(i)));
    k2 = exp((172140 - 177.7.*T3(i))./(-R.*T3(i)));

    x_co = k6 * k2 / p;
    x_h2 = (p-k6*k2*(k6+1))/(p*(k7+1));

    ov_x_co3 = [ov_x_co3; x_co];
    ov_x_h23 = [ov_x_h23; x_h2];
end

% Combine data from all scripts
T = [T1, T2, T3];
ov_x_co = [ov_x_co1; ov_x_co2; ov_x_co3];
ov_x_h2 = [ov_x_h21; ov_x_h22; ov_x_h23];

% Iterate through the array
for i = 1:size(ov_x_h2, 1)   % Rows
    for j = 1:size(ov_x_h2, 2)   % Columns
        if ov_x_h2(i, j) < 0 || ov_x_h2(i, j) > 1
            ov_x_h2(i, j) = NaN;
        end
    end
end

% Iterate through the array
for i = 1:size(ov_x_co, 1)   % Rows
    for j = 1:size(ov_x_co, 2)   % Columns
        if ov_x_co(i, j) < 0 || ov_x_co(i, j) > 1
            ov_x_co(i, j) = NaN;
        end
    end
end

% Plot 3D data
figure;
plot3(T, ov_x_co, ov_x_h2, '-', 'LineWidth', 2.5, 'Color', 'black');
hold on;

% Script 1
T = 700:10:1200;
ov_x_co = [];
ov_x_h2 = [];
ov_x_h2o = [];
ov_x_co2 = [];
ov_T = [];

for i = 1:numel(T)
    k1 = exp((36580 - 33.465.*T(i))./(-R.*T(i)));
    k2 = exp((172140 - 177.7.*T(i))./(-R.*T(i)));

    x_co = 0.0:0.05:1.0;
    x_co2 = zeros(1, numel(x_co));
    x_h2 = zeros(1, numel(x_co));
    x_h2o = zeros(1, numel(x_co));
    var_temp = T(i)*ones(1, numel(x_co));
    ov_T = [ov_T; var_temp];

    for j = 1:numel(x_co)    
        x_co2(j) = x_co(j).^2 ./ k2;
        x_h2(j) = ((x_co(j)./(x_co2(j) .* k1)).*(1-x_co(j)-x_co2(j)))./(1+(x_co(j)./(x_co2(j).*k1)));
        x_h2o(j) = 1 - x_co(j) - x_co2(j) - x_h2(j);
    end

    ov_x_co = [ov_x_co;x_co];
    ov_x_h2 = [ov_x_h2; x_h2];
    ov_x_h2o = [ov_x_h2o; x_h2o];
    ov_x_co2 = [ov_x_co2; x_co2];
end

% Iterate through the array
for i = 1:size(ov_x_h2, 1)   % Rows
    for j = 1:size(ov_x_h2, 2)   % Columns
        if ov_x_h2(i, j) < 0 || ov_x_h2(i, j) > 1
            ov_x_h2(i, j) = NaN;
        end
    end
end

colorValue = 0.2;  % Set the desired constant color value
C = ones(size(ov_x_co)) * colorValue;

surf(ov_T, ov_x_co, ov_x_h2);
colormap('parula');
%surf(ov_T, ov_x_co, ov_x_h2, C, 'EdgeColor', 'none');

hold off;

ylim([0, 1]);
zlim([0, 1]);
xlabel('T (K)');
ylabel('x_{CO}');
zlabel('x_{H2}');
title('Combined 3D Plots');
legend('Script 2', 'Script 1');
grid on;
```

Comment: It would be good if you included an image of the plot you were able to make, and one modified to show what you want to accomplish. It is hard to understand your words without being familiar with your field.

Comment: To find the intersections i would subtract (probably needs padding) the lines and the surface.  Then it's not quite clear to me what you want to do, but i think contour() function might be useful

Comment: As Cris Luengo said, please find a picture looking like your expected result (or crudely draw one by hand). To me, It sounds like the 3D line are along the surface and you want to color the surface differently between different sets of these 3D lines ... but that's just a guess. You need to be clearer in what you are asking.

Comment: Is I see what you want. Interesting. I *think* you need to split the surface into separate pieces, and draw each piece as its own `surf`. But maybe I’m wrong about that. There’s a way to render a bitmap on a surface, maybe that is another way to draw these colors?